# Discord.Net - Add reaction to previous message from command

Tags: c#, discord.net

From a command, I want to be able to grab the previous message from the chat and add reactions to that message. I am using this line of code to get the previous message but it returns a `IEnumerable<IMessage>`.

```
var messages = await Context.Channel
                   .GetMessagesAsync(Context.Message, Direction.Before, 1)
                   .FlattenAsync();
```

`IMessages` do not have an add reaction function. I tried going through multiple ways to get the socket user message from the last message but can not find any way to get a socket user message from an IMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast to an `IUserMessage`.
If cache isn't enabled you won't be able to get a socket message, you'd get a rest message instead. That said, a socket message isn't required, so the interface should suffice.